# Sagemaker Regression - ValueError: Cannot format input

Tags: python, linear-regression, amazon-sagemaker

I am new to SageMaker & Python

I am trying to get a simple regression model going on AWS using Jupyter Notebooks.
I am using the Abalone date from the  UCI data repository.
I would greatly appreciate some assistance or a link to help me in what to do.

Everything looks fine until I try to run:

```
regression_linear = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    container,
    role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
    input_mode = "File",
    instance_count = 1,
    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
    output_path=output_location,
    sagemaker_session=sess
    )

regression_linear.set_hyperparameters(
    feature_dim=8,
    epochs=16,
    wd=0.01,
    loss="absolute_loss",
    predictor_type="regressor",
    normalize_data=True,
    optimizer="adam",
    mini_batch_size=100,
    lr_scheduler_step=100,
    lr_scheduler_factor=0.99,
    lr_scheduler_minimum_lr=0.0001,
    learning_rate=0.1,
    )

from time import gmtime, strftime
job_name = "DEMO-linear-learner-abalone-regression-" + strftime("%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
print("Training job: ", job_name)

regression_linear.fit(inputs={"train": train_data}, job_name=job_name)
```

Then I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-82bd2950b590> in <module>
----> 1 regression_linear.fit(inputs={"train": train_data}, job_name=job_name)
      2 
      3 # , "validation": test_data

ValueError: Cannot format input       age  sex  length  diameter  height  whole_weight  shucked_weight  \
449    18    0   0.565     0.455   0.150        0.8205          0.3650   
1080    7    1   0.430     0.335   0.120        0.3970          0.1985   
2310   13    0   0.435     0.350   0.110        0.3840          0.1430   
3790   10    0   0.650     0.505   0.175        1.2075          0.5105   
3609    9    0   0.555     0.405   0.120        0.9130          0.4585   
...   ...  ...     ...       ...     ...           ...             ...   
2145    9    0   0.415     0.325   0.115        0.3455          0.1405   
3815    8   -1   0.460     0.340   0.100        0.3860          0.1805   
3534    6   -1   0.400     0.315   0.090        0.3300          0.1510   
2217   13    0   0.515     0.415   0.130        0.7640          0.2760   
3041    9    1   0.575     0.470   0.150        0.9785          0.4505   

      vicera_weight  shell_weight  
449          0.1590        0.2600  
1080         0.0865        0.1035  
2310         0.1005        0.1250  
3790         0.2620        0.3900  
3609         0.1960        0.2065  
...             ...           ...  
2145         0.0765        0.1100  
3815         0.0875        0.0965  
3534         0.0680        0.0800  
2217         0.1960        0.2500  
3041         0.1960        0.2760  

[2923 rows x 9 columns]. Expecting one of str, TrainingInput, file_input or FileSystemInput
```